# How to stop jQuery dialog to delete the original content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dialog

So I have an image on my website. When I click on that image a jQuery dialog pops up and places that image in my dialog. The only problem is that my image disappears from my website. So I only have my image in my dialog and not on my website anymore. How do I change it so that the image stays on my website even after it goes into my dialog after clicking the image?

Here's my code:

```
<body>
<img src="http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/FRONT_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg"
     data-swap="http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg" id="images">

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').jqueryPlugin();
        });
    });
</script
```

And here's my javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.jqueryPlugin = function () {
        $("#images").click(function () {
            var _this = $(this);
            var current = _this.attr("src");
            var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");

            _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap", current);

            $("#images").dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                resize: "auto"
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer??

Answer (score 0):

use below code .  when dialog close again swap image src and destroy dialog box. see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/n3eenbLr/)

if you want to keep image in background when dialog open please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/n3eenbLr/1/)

have add another [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/n3eenbLr/2/) withe some update

```
 $("#images").dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            resize: "auto",
            close : function(){
               $("#images").dialog( "destroy" );
             _this.attr('src', current).attr("data-swap",swap);
        }
    });
```